# How can I access IntelliJ's java compiler from the command line?

Tags: java, linux, maven, intellij-idea, fedora

I have a very large maven project, and when I'm debugging, it sucks to have to rebuild the entire project just to see the changes. My current method is to compile the java file in IntelliJ, then copy the class file in my target directory, to my tomcat/webapps/project/ directory, and replace the existing class file with the intellij compiled class file. Then rebuild the war file, and replace it with the existing war file in the tomcat/webapps directory.

I want to be able to automate this process. I looked into doing it with the javac command, but I'm having problems with packages be imported from jar files in the .m2 directory, and can't figure out how to automate the classpath, depending on the specific file. I'm sure IntelliJ does this automatically, and was wondering if there's a way to run IntelliJ's compiler from the command line, or if anyone has any insight into how I can get javac to work for just the one file in my whole project scope.

Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Since you are using maven, then you can use the [mvn](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) command

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you're trying to deploy, but you should be able to do something like war-in-place and point Tomcat at the exploded war instead of copying.

Comment: You're using Maven.  Do you see a tab on the right-hand side that says "Maven"?  This is how you can import your project in with Maven should you so desire.

Comment: I'm not actually using a maven interface or anything. Didn't even know there was one. This project has a build script that runs `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true verify $1`. Have never used maven before, so I'm not entirely sure how it works. But from my understanding, it builds the whole project. I want to be able to only compile the one class, then replace it in the already built project.

Comment: How long does that Maven command take? If you want incremental builds, then use Gradle.

Comment: Can take anywhere from 3-5 minutes.

Comment: The best you can do is to run the server from within IntelliJ, either by Maven, or better yet programmatically or via IntelliJ Ultimate integration. Then you can use hotswap or simply restart after that one file was changed, and forget about manually compiling one class.

Comment: Another thing to try is to deploy to Tomcat as usual, attach IntelliJ to the debug port on the remote so you can debug the code and then just recompile in IntelliJ. Depending on the changes you've made, your updated classes will then be hot swapped without restarting the server. I haven't tried this in Tomcat but it works fine with Weblogic.

If you can get http://hotswapagent.org/ running, it'll even hot swap when you change the class structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ delegates (by default, there are options to delegate to the Eclipse compiler or other ones) to the javac compiler.

If you do not want to import your project into IntelliJ, then you can use maven from the command line to build the project.

If you do not want to build the whole project, then you can use javac from the command line.

To generate your classpath, use :
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt

classpath.txt will contain your classpath.

From then you can do : javac -cp (contents of classpath.txt) your java file.

IntelliJ is fast even on large maven projects and it can easily compile into an exploded war your tomcat would point to. It is unclear to me on why you would not want to benefit from IntelliJ.

Comment: I forgot to mention that IntelliJ is on my local machine, and the tomcat server is on a vm, so I'd have to scp it over. The source files that I work out of are mounted onto my local machine from the server. However, that mvn command to generate the classpath worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!